# Visualforce Render Details Tab as PDF - Opens Blank PDF

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning, pdf

I want to open case details in PDF view when clicking on custom button in Lightning.
I have a custom button(added it to standard layout) with Content Source Visualforce Page.

Below is my VF Code:

```
<apex:page StandardController="Case" extensions="ConvertToPDF" renderAs="pdf" applyHtmlTag="true"  applyBodyTag="true" sideBar="false">
   <apex:includeLightning />
<apex:outputtext value="{!CaseURL}" escape="false" style="position: absolute;top: 0;"/>
</apex:page>
```

In My controller:

```
            String Id  = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');    
            String URL = '/'+Id;
            return (new PageReference(URL).getContent().toString());
```

I am able to open new tab but the PDF is rendered as Blank.

Answer (score 0):

I think `applyHtmlTag="false"`  and `applyBodyTag="false"` should be there as `apex:page` attributes to open the page in pdf.

Comment: I tried the same. Doesn't work.